# Is there a way to make a string equal to a number in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an input text field that autosuggests when the user is typing from a list of preselected words in an array. It works fine with the following:

```
<div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="CITY" name="cityId" required>
</div>

var cities = ["Tampa","Atlanta","Denver","Detroit", etc.... ]
```

but I need to assign a numeric value to each city in order for the search to work correctly... I'm new to js... Can I just edit the array somehow?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var areasforsale = ["Agate","Aguilar","Akron","Alamosa","Allenspark","Alma","Antonito","Arapahoe","Arriba"];

function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
              b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
      x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
    }
  }
}
/*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
});
}

autocomplete(document.getElementById("areaforsale"), areasforsale);

</script>
```

I'm just trying to figure out how to assign a numeric value to each city, so when I submit the form, the method="get" puts the number in the address bar and not the city name

Comment: This is not basic HTML functionality. You must be using some javascript library. Try to find out which one.

Comment: A `.map()` should do it. Iterate over cities, and create an array of objects like `{"Tempa": 1}` so on. But it would greatly help if you show us more code.

Comment: We need to see some more code to give you a proper answer, but just as an idea, you could create an object which would have both the name and number if you wanted.

Comment: It's pointless suggesting anything until we know what autocomplete library OP is using. Most provide a way to separate value and label

Comment: I'm simply asking for the vernacular on how to assign a number to a city like it was just mentioned:

{"Tampa": 1} That is correct yes? sorry I'm kind of new to all this

Comment: @user3547342 objects are one way to go. `obj = {1: "Tampa"}` so `obj[1]` gives `"Tampa"`. Or you can use a plain array and use the indexes as the numbers (and apply appropriate offset if needed). `arr =["Tampa"]; num = 1;` so `arr[num-1]` gives `"Tampa"`

Comment: @user3547342 please edit your code so that we can see what you currently have supplying the auto-suggestions. It will be easier to show you an example by modifying your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
[
  {id: 1, city: "Tampa"},
  {id: 2, city: "Atlanta"},
  {id: 3, city: "Denver"},
  {id: 4, city: "Detroit"},
  {id: 5, city: "etc..."}
]
```

Then find the javascript object where it returns the city name and add ".city" to it so it's reading out the city string to the user.

something like

```
// return objectName;
return objectName.city;
```

and do whatever you wanted with the id

```
objectName.id;
```

I would suggest doing some reading about objects/arrays, and some basic Javascript 101. It doesn't matter what language you work with in the future, these things are important to understand in any language. The syntax and logic looks extremely similar in all languages across the entire stack.

https://jsfiddle.net/ is a great place to experiment as you learn, and even share bits of code with others to learn more.

**EDIT** 
Now that I see you added some JS code in your post, you would have to modify every part where it accesses the array. For example:

```
// arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == .....
arr[i].city.substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == .....
```

Your only other option would be to use the array index as your identifier in order to limit editing the current Javascript, but that brings other issues if the array changes. If you end up wanting to access that city by it's number (or id) later then you'd be in trouble if that array changes length or order. Pick your poison.

Comment: thanks for the response. no I'd never want to access a city by its number in the future..